# How to send an image in direct message?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to send an image in direct message using python + tweepy but no luck.
It showed as a link in incoming messages.

```
imgurl = 'https://t.co/***'
api.send_direct_message(screen_name='username',text=' '+imgurl)
```

Could you please advise?
Official Twitter API doesn't shed a light for me as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, you *are* sending a link. Literally a status message where the text is a URL.

Sadly, [Twitter don't provide API access for uploading images via DM](https://twittercommunity.com/t/uploading-images-in-dms/12317/4).

If you are able to use Twitter's private API, you should be able to attach a `media_id` to your DM.  But other than that, you're out of luck.

Sorry.