# How can I attach an image to a "Direct Message" in twitter Android?

Tags: android, twitter, xamarin.android

I programmed an app that can send a message to twitter with an image attached. It works! I tested it on several devices and asked other people to do the same. It even works for a Direct Message when a twitter friend is selected. However, it does not work when "Direct Message" is selected. This forces the user to select a friend directly instead of selecting him via "Direct Message" (which is really strange) otherwise the picture is not attached. Just have a look at the screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of intent chooser]

Here is my Xamarin Android programming code. Let me know how to fix it. Currently, all options work, even selecting my friend **but not "Direct Message"**. I also need to tell that I do not have any issue with the twitter text I expect to see in the tweet.

```
        public bool TweetImage(Bitmap imageToTweet)
    {
        var messageIntent = context.FindMessageIntent(this.twitterConstants.PackageName);
        if (messageIntent == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        string outputFileBMP = SaveBitmap(imageToTweet);
        context.Tweet(messageIntent, outputFileBMP, this.twitterConstants.DefaultTwitterText, this.twitterConstants.ChooserMessage);
        return true;
    }
```

and

```
        public static Intent FindMessageIntent(this ContextWrapper contextWrapper, params string[] packageNames)
    {
        Intent wantedIntent = new Intent();
        wantedIntent.SetType("text/plain");

        var resolveInfos = contextWrapper.PackageManager.QueryIntentActivities(wantedIntent, PackageInfoFlags.MatchDefaultOnly);

        var result =  (from r in resolveInfos
                       from p in packageNames
                       where p == r.ActivityInfo.PackageName
                       select p).FirstOrDefault();

        if (result != null)
        {
            wantedIntent.SetPackage(result);
            return wantedIntent;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

and

```
        public static void Tweet(this ContextWrapper contextWrapper, Intent messageIntent, string filePath = null, string message = null, string chooserMessage = null)
    {
        if (filePath != null)
        {
            using (var file = new Java.IO.File(filePath))
            {
                messageIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(file));
            }
        }
        if (message != null)
        {
            messageIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraText, message);
        }

        if (chooserMessage != null)
        {
            using (var chooser = Intent.CreateChooser(messageIntent, chooserMessage))
            {
                contextWrapper.StartActivity(chooser);
            }
            return;
        }
        contextWrapper.StartActivity(messageIntent);
    }
```

Please note that I am using Android and need a solution based on Android (intent based).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send an image in direct message?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37345016/how-to-send-an-image-in-direct-message)

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, [Twitter don't provide API access for uploading images via DM](https://twittercommunity.com/t/uploading-images-in-dms/12317/4).

If you are able to use Twitter's private API, you should be able to attach a `media_id` to your DM.  But other than that, you're out of luck.

Sorry.

Comment: I think I already succeeded in uploading images via DM. This is exactly what happens when I select a friend. It works, do not worry about that. I just try to make it work in situations where not the friend but just "Direct Message" is selected.